# Telescoping series seems not telescoping

Tags: telescopic-series

In the following example of the book Partial Differential Equation, An Introduction 2nd edition from Strauss, on page 127, they assert the following:

Let $f_n(x) = (1-x)x^{n-1}$ on the interval $ 0 < x < 1$. Then the series is telescoping. The partial sums are
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i = 1}^N f_n(x) = 1 - x^N
\end{equation}
Why does this series telescope? Computing partial sums does not yield cancellations.

Comment: What did you get when writing down the first partial sums? Why do you think that there is no cancellation?

Comment: I never computed the products, so for each term I had just written: \begin{equation} \sum_{i = 1}^N f_n(x) = 1 + (1-x)x^1 + (1-x)x^2 \dots \end{equation}

Comment: And how is this related to partial derivatives?

Comment: This is basic theory for the convergence of the fourier series.

Answer (score 4):

$\require{cancel}$Note that $f_n(x)=x^{n-1}-x^n$ and that therefore$$\sum_{i=1}^Nf_n(x)=1-\cancel x+\cancel x-\cancel{x^2}+\cancel{x^2}-\cdots-\cancel{x^{N-1}}+\cancel{x^{N-1}}-x^N.$$So, yes, it is telescoping.

Comment: Of course! Should've seen that, made a mistake in computing the series. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is a [telescopic sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)! Note that 
$$\sum_{i = 1}^N f_n(x)=\sum_{i = 1}^N (x^{n-1}-x^n)=(1-x)+(x-x^2)+\dots+(x^{N-1}-x^N)=1-x^N.$$

Comment: Of course! Should've seen that, made a mistake in computing the series. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Strauss clearly writes in the book (page 126) you mentioned:

> Let $f_n(x)=(1-x)x^{n-1}$ on the interval $0<x<1$. Then the series is "telescoping." The partial sums are
>   $$
> \sum_1^Nf_n(x)=\sum_1^N(x^{n-1}-x^n)=1-x^N\to 1\quad \textrm{as }N\to\infty.
> $$

Here is the original excerpt from the book.

> [image]

Comment: I did not find the identity $\sum f_n(x) = \sum_1^N (x^{n-1} - x^n)$

Comment: @Rice4000 Which edition are you reading? You should probably find the newest edition.

Comment: @Rice4000 Compare your text with http://jingweizhu.weebly.com/uploads/1/3/5/4/13548262/partial-differential-equations.pdf

Comment: @Rice4000: I'm surprised you do not find that identity in Strauss's book since you have mentioned "edition 2" in your post.